# Redis sort by likes inside list of hashes?

Tags: node.js, hash, redis

Sorry if my terminology is wrong, but I have a list of `feed` hashes.

So ie `feed:1, feed:2, feed:3` inside those hashes I have some keys and values. ie inside `feed:1` I have `likes:300`.

I have a list called `feeds:fid` which lists all the feed ids. So if I want to grab all the feeds I can just do a method like this in my node.js

```
module.getObjects = function(keys, callback) {
    helpers.multiKeys(redisClient, 'hgetall', keys, callback);
};
```

I am not sure how I can sort them so I get all feed items sorted by most liked? Ideally I just want to get the "hottest feed" items.

I am curious how I can go about this in redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be difficult to do in your current set of things.
You can however use a single sorted set to store likes along with feed ids.
So,whenever a like happens, you store the like in your hash, but also do an 
[ZINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/ZINCRBY) operation on the same feed key in the sorted set.

-- At any point of time the sorted set will contain the feed ids as keys, and number of likes on the key as the score.

-- To get top or hottest feeds, you just do a [ZREVRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrange) operation, which will give you top N items with maximum likes.

-- To keep both your operations atomic, you shall use redis [transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) to have data always synched between hash and sorted set.

Comment: Cool, this is helpful, still a little over my head but after digging a but deeper I am sure it will make much more sense. I have one more set it looks like `fid:1:users_liked` which contains a list of all the users that liked that feed, not sure if that is helpful.

Comment: Also I did try a `ZREVRANGE` before `ZREVRANGE feeds:fid 0 -1` I just get them returned by fid highest to lowest.